Can I disable Images to be transferred to my app on React Native Expo?
On android, users can transfer images from one app to another, for example, I can transfer an image from the Whatsapp file storage folder, to eBay file storage folder.
Is there any way in React Native, to prevent users from transferring images INTO my app.
If this helps understand, This is the current code I have to save images locally to MY app. This is working fine.
        await FileSystem.copyAsync({
            from: photoURI,
            to: FileSystem.documentDirectory + photoID + '.jpg'
        });


